# how to redesign all table td in tr rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td> A-1 </td>
   <td> A-2 </td>
   <td> A-3 </td>
   <td> A-4 </td>
   <td> A-5 </td>
   <td> A-6 </td>
   <td> A-7 </td>
   <td> A-8 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> B-1 </td>
   <td> B-2 </td>
   <td> B-3 </td>
   <td> B-4 </td>
   <td> B-5 </td>
   <td> B-6 </td>
   <td colspan=2> B-7 </td>
</tr> </table>
```

it's something like this:

A-1 A-2 A-3 A-4 A-5 A-6 A-7 A-8

B-1 B-2 B-3 B-4 B-5 B-6 B-8

During some change on page size i want to change that  table to be like following table design:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td> A-1 </td>
   <td> A-2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> A-3 </td>
   <td> A-4 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> A-5 </td>
   <td> A-6 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> A-7 </td>
   <td> A-8 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> B-1 </td>
   <td> B-2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> B-3 </td>
   <td> B-4 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> B-5 </td>
   <td> B-6 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan=2> B-7 </td>
</tr> </table>
```

It's something like this:

A-1 A-2

A-3 A-4

A-5 A-6

..

B-7

I'm not sure if that can be done with css or javascript.

Comment: How do you want to design the table!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using tables instead of divs?  Tables are harder to make responsive - divs would be easier in my opinion. If you have to keep using tables, it will be a mostly JS solution.

Comment: is you table static or do you have A1,A2,A3.... store in an array?

Comment: @ewald I'm using this table as bootstrap table and it's easy to manage it with different plug-in with

Comment: I see, yes, then you will need to use JavaScript to manipulate the HTML on changes. I see someone has posted a promising answer, best wishes with your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.querySelectorAll("#table1 td")` to select all `td`, then use `[].forEach.call`, this way you can loop through a Element List, and buld the new table.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td");
var _html = "<table>";
[].forEach.call(x, function(el, i) {
    if(i%2==0) _html += "<tr>";
    _html += el.outerHTML;
    if(i%2==1) _html += "</tr>";
});

_html += "</table>";

alert(_html);

document.write(_html);
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>A-1</td>
    <td>A-2</td>
    <td>A-3</td>
    <td>A-4</td>
    <td>A-5</td>
    <td>A-6</td>
    <td>A-7</td>
    <td>A-8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B-1</td>
    <td>B-2</td>
    <td>B-3</td>
    <td>B-4</td>
    <td>B-5</td>
    <td>B-6</td>
    <td>B-7</td>
    <td>B-8</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Will document.write delete the entire content of the page?

Comment: @Roberto If the content is completely loaded, it will open a new document which seems like the previous one is erased, otherwise it just writes line by line. document.wrie is mainly used for testing purpose only.

Comment: @void Thanks for your quick code, if you noticed I have colspan the last td in the second tr but your code didn't cover that also the document.write delete all the html page content and this shouldn't happened

Comment: @void still, it's keep 2 td in 8 tr even there is colspan, it's need to moved to the new tr